# How to use CURL command in groovy script

Tags: jenkins, curl, groovy

I am using below curl command:

```
curl -u "nnarayan1" https://ipsddress:port/api/v3/orgs/RB-Health-rbESB/repos --insecure
```

How can I get output of above curl command using groovy scripting?

Kindly suggest groovy script for this.

I tried different solution from stackoverflow, none of them is working.

Comment: please edit your question and provide the following info: `1.` are you using jenkins pipeline or just groovy step jenkins? `2.` provide the code what have you tried so far and describe the problem. why do you think it's not working..

Comment: Why not use groovier solution such as https://http-builder-ng.github.io/http-builder-ng/asciidoc/html5/

Comment: I am using jenkins job, just groovy steps in jenkins.

Comment: I tried using below script.

Comment: package com.rb
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def orgName = "RB-Health-rbPLM"

def accessToken = "3bda530c9c5f84ddbbf62964fb070668c5db2435"//Generate a token for user. Not user password
def apiUrl = "https://10.38.23.222/api/v3/orgs/RB-Health-rbESB/repos"

def jsonSlurper = new JsonSlurper()
def listener = new StringBuilder(), err = new StringBui

Answer (score 1):

```
def res = sh(script: 'curl --insecure -u nnarayan1 https://ipaddress:port/api/v3/orgs/RB-Health-rbESB/repos', returnStdout: true)
```

Comment: Please explain that how your answer will help to solve the problem, and just don't give code only answer without context.

Answer (score 1):

```
def response
response = sh(
    script: 'curl --insecure -u nnarayan1 https://ipsddress:port/api/v3/orgs/RB-Health-rbESB/repos',
    returnStdout: true
)
```

I would personally avoid specifying the "--insecure" flag.